# div position fixed - but no scroll (Confluence)

Tags: html, css

I'm currently using the following code for my `div` element

```
div.fixed 
{
 position: fixed !important;  
 top: 0px !important;
 right: 0px !important;
 width: 300px;
 text-align:right !important;
 margin-right: 20px !important;  
}
```

It works great and, as originally intended, scrolls with the content. However, I would like it to **not** scroll. I've used other **position** properties but they push my `div` to the middle of the page. Have had some success with **position:absolute** but that then covers up other elements.

What I am hoping for is that the div stays in place as it does when using `fixed` but **does not** scroll along with the page.

Possible?

Answer (score 0):

Well you would be looking for `relative` or `absolute`. There could be others but I can't help much without seeing your code. Try putting it in a fiddle or something.

Why are you using `!important`?

Comment: I'm using **!important** to force confluence in accepting the CSS otherwise it doesn't in most case (since it has its own underlying CSS precedence).

**absolute** helps but covers up other elements on the screen/window.

Comment: Maybe use `z-index` set to some negative value to force element not to cover others?